# Vagrant hostname that differs from machine name

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, hostname

It seems that no matter what I set as the `vm.hostname` value, running the command `hostname` yields the vagrant machine's name instead of the hostname I provided.

So, given this setup:

```ruby
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.define "site1" do |s1_conf|
    s1_conf.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'
    s1_conf.vm.hostname = 'site1.dev'
  end
  config.vm.define "site2" do |s2_conf|
    s2_conf.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'
    s1_conf.vm.hostname = 'site2.dev'
  end
end
```

If I do `vagrant ssh site2` and then `hostname`, I'll get "site2" **not** "site2.dev". Why?

Is my understanding of how this works wrong? Or is it supposed to work this way, and I have something else going on in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Invalid Hostname Character

`.` is not a valid character for the hostname portion of a fully-qualified domain name (FQDN). Try `site1-dev` or `site2-dev` instead.